# How is the set of rational numbers countably infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How is $\mathbb{Q}$ countably infinite?

The definition says all elements of the set must have a one-to-one relation to the natural numbers. I do not understand this.

How do the elements in $\mathbb{Q}$ have a one-to-one relation with natural numbers?

Comment: Do you see that  $\mathbb{N}$ , $\mathbb{Z}$ and  $\mathbb{Z}^2$  all have the same cardinality?

Comment: you've already asked this question and I've posted a solution. Also I'm sure that if you googled "rational numbers countable proof" it would be the first link to appear.

Comment: Just for the record see [that](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite).

Answer (score 2):

Because you can construct
a mapping of the rationals
into the integers.

One easy way is to map
the positive rational
$\dfrac{a}{b}$
to the integer
$2^a 3^b$.

This shows that
there are at least as many integers
as there are positive rationals.

Answer (score 0):

**[There are many proofs here.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite)**

---

For the sake of completeness I will write one down here.

> The rational numbers are arranged thus $$\frac {0}{1}, \frac {1}{1}, \frac {-1}{1},\frac {1}{2},\frac {-1}{2},\frac {2}{1 },\frac {-2}{1},\frac {1}{3},\frac {2}{3},\cdots $$
>
> > It is clear that every rational number will appear somewhere in this list. Thus it is possible to set up a bijection between each rational number and its position in the list, which is an element of $\mathbb N $.

Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333221/how-to-prove-that-the-set-of-rational-numbers-are-countable). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A roundabout way of showing this is to express the elements of $\mathbb{Q} - \{0\}$ as products of prime numbers.  Labeling the prime numbers as $p_1, p_2, ...$ every nonzero rational number can be uniquely expressed as a product

$$p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} \cdots$$

where $n_i$ are integers and for all but finitely many $i$, $n_i = 0$.

Your question becomes equivalent to asking why the set $A$ of sequences of integers $(n_1,n_2, ...)$ such that $n_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i$, is countable.

To show this, let $A_j$ be the set of integer sequences $(n_1, ... , n_j, 0, 0, ...)$.  Then $A_j$ is clearly in bijection with $\prod\limits_{i=1}^j \mathbb{Z}$, which is countable, and $A$ is equal to the union of the $A_j$.  Now, you just have to show that a countable union of countable sets is countable.